# why is my check box unselecting after I click the next one in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have multiple checkboxes and when I click one and click the next, the previous one is getting unselected do you know why this is?

Here is my checkbox component:

```
const Checkbox = ({ key, id, label, checked, name, onChange,  }:any) => {

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-wrapper">
      <input multiple key={id} id={id} type="checkbox" checked={checked} name={name} onChange={onChange} />
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
```

this is what the main component looks like, with data in an array and then it is being mapped out, however I'm not sure why its deselcting the previous checkbox, I have removed a lot of the other useless code in the jsx:

```
const checkboxList = [

  {
    id:0,
    label:"upperCase",
    name: "upper",
    checked:false

  },
  {
    id:1,
    label:"lowerCase",
    name: "lower",
    checked:false

  },
  {
    id:2,
    label:"numbercase",
    name: "number",
    checked:false

  },
  {
    id:3,
    label:"symbolcase",
    name: "symbols",
    checked:false

  }
]

const PasswordGenerator = () => {


const [data, setData] = useState( checkboxList)

 
  const handleChange = (id:number) => {
    const updateCheckboxes = checkboxList.map((checkbox) => 
    checkbox.id === id ? {...checkbox, checked: !checkbox.checked}:checkbox)

    setData(updateCheckboxes)

  }


  return (
    
      <div  className="elements">
        {data.map((obj) => {

          return(
            <div key={obj.id}>
          <Checkbox
          multiple={true}
          id={obj.id}
          label = {obj.label}
          checked= {obj.checked}
          name= {obj.name}
          onChange = {() => handleChange(obj.id)}
          />
        </div>

          )
        })}
        </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you update state, you’re updating from the original array rather than from the current state.  Instead of mapping from the original array (checkboxList), map from the current value of state (data):

```
const handleChange = (id:number) => {
  const updateCheckboxes = data.map((checkbox) => 
    checkbox.id === id ? {...checkbox, checked: !checkbox.checked}:checkbox)

  setData(updateCheckboxes)
}
```